# Error message when running mongo container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have currently a problem with `mongoDB` and `Docker`:

I have this error when I compose up:

```
ERROR: Named volume "mongo:/data/db:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Comment: Maybe you mount this volume on host directory

Comment: Post your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: I have posted my real problem, in fact, i have a volume instead a container and i have to delete an index from one collection in the database but i can't have acces to the volume data ....

Comment: You should add `volumes: mongo:` at the end of `docker-compose.yml` file. Also do not write answer when you want to ask and add details to your question. Please use `Edit` button below the question and at top of `Comments` section.

Comment: I have already tried by adding the mongo container and the volumes like you said but when i create the container and when i'm using the shell, there is no data, no database whereas my volume have 2 databases... It's look like the container is not sync with the volume ....

Comment: I have to delete an index from one collection and i have juste one mongodb volume, no container actually.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, i realized that i have a volume instead a container but i can't access to the data or manipulate them with the mongo shell.

I have to delete an index from one mongodb collection in the volume.

How i can do that knowing that i have no container but i have a volume instead.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - $CERT_DIR:/etc/nginx/certs

  app:
    image: registry.eksae.fr/talent:${VERSION:-latest}
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN=${SENTRY_DSN}
      - NEXT_SERVER_MONGODB_URI
      - NEXT_SERVER_MONGODB_USER
      - NEXT_SERVER_MONGODB_PASSWORD
      - NEXT_SERVER_MONGODB_DBNAME
      - NEXT_SERVER_MONGODB_DEBUG
      - NEXT_SERVER_MAILER_HOST
      - NEXT_SERVER_MAILER_PORT
      - NEXT_SERVER_MAILER_USER
      - NEXT_SERVER_MAILER_PASS
      - NEXT_SERVER_MAILER_SECURE
      - NEXT_SERVER_REDIS_HOST
      - NEXT_SERVER_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DAYS
      - SENTRY_DSN
      - SENTRY_RELEASE
      - SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT
      - SENTRY_ORG
      - SENTRY_PROJECT
      - SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000
      - VIRTUAL_HOST
      - CERT_NAME
    extra_hosts:
      - s0003113:10.100.173.107
      - s0003112:10.100.173.106
      - s0003110:10.100.173.105
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

volumes:
  redis:
    driver: local
```